# Unexpected EOF using echo <<<EOT in if/elseif block

Tags: php

I need to have an if/elseif statement on page that needs to echo quite a few HTML lines. For simplicity, instead of escaping all the quotes I would just like PHP to ignore the quotes so I'm using `echo <<<EOT .... EOT;`

Now the problem is this compiles just fine:

```
    if ($lang == "en") {
        echo <<<EOT
           some html
EOT;
    }
```

But this throws an `syntax error, unexpected end of file`:

```
    if ($lang == "en") {
        echo <<<EOT
           some html
EOT;
    }
    elseif ($lang == "sp") {
        echo <<<EOT
           some html
EOT;                        
    }
```

It's obviously the use of multiple EOT in a if/elseif that's causing the problem. How can I work around this? Or rather what would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have white-space after the 2nd `EOT;` So you need to delete those white spaces.
I tested this after removing the white space and it works.

So you can not have white space in the line that has `EOT;` just the `EOT;`

```
if ($lang == "en") {    
    echo <<<EOT
           some html
EOT;
}elseif ($lang == "sp"){
  echo <<<EOT
         some html
EOT;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

white-space should not after `heredoc` starting and before end tag: for more info [**click here**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
              _____________No white space here
              |
             \/
  echo <<<EOT
    some html
 EOT;
/\
|_________No white space here
```